# How to check that a ruby value is a non-negative float?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In rspec, suppose I have a value x
How can I check that x is a non-negative floating point value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
object.should be_a(Float)
object.should be >= 0.0
```

Comment: This is old fashioned.

Answer (score 6):

I would do something like this:

```
expect(value).to be_a(Float)
expect(value).to be >= 0
```

In newer versions of Ruby you can even write:

```
expect(value).to be_positive
```

Comment: This is the preferred RSpec 3 syntax

Answer (score 2):

In rspec 3 you can combine multiple expectations with `and`

```
 expect(value).to be_a(Float).and be >= 0
```

You can also use `or` to combine matchers, these are aliased to `&` and `|`